# Output being printed twice

Tags: java, sockets, system.out

I'm attempting to use sockets to program client and server interactions. The user can read their messages, compose a message to someone, and exit. Everything works properly except "NO MESSAGES" is printing out twice instead of once and I can't figure out why. I'll put the relevant code below, any help would be great. Thanks!

Client.java

```
     import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String messages = "";

    // Makes sure there are only two arguments entered

        if(args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java Client <host name> <port number>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Stores the command line arguments for readability further in the program
        String host = args[0];
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        try (

            // Creates the socket to be used
            Socket s = new Socket(host, port);

            // Reader and Writer to talk with Server
            PrintWriter pw =
                        new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        ) {

            // Reader to read from standard input (keyboard)
            BufferedReader keyboard =
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


        // User interface
        while (true) {

        System.out.println("Please enter your username: ");
        String username = keyboard.readLine();

            // Check that the login is valid
            if (username == null) {
            System.out.println("No username entered");
            }
            else if (username.contains(" ")) {
            System.out.println("Username cannot contain spaces");
            }
                // Send username to server and return number of messages
            else {
                pw.println(username);
            messages = bf.readLine();
            System.out.println("You have " + Integer.parseInt(messages) + " messages");
            break;
            }
        }

        // Enable the user to continue reading and composing messages until
        // they choose to exit
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Would you like to READ, COMPOSE or EXIT?");
            String choice = keyboard.readLine();

        // Shows the messages left for the user
                if (choice.equals("READ")) {
            pw.println("READ");
            messages = bf.readLine();
                    if (Integer.parseInt(messages) == 0) {
                        System.out.println("NO MESSAGES");
            }
            else {
            String incoming = bf.readLine();
            System.out.println(incoming);
                        incoming = bf.readLine();
            System.out.println(incoming);
            }
            }
        // Allows user to write a message to another user
            else if (choice.equals("COMPOSE")) {
            pw.println("COMPOSE");
            // I've separated this into two lines for readability
            System.out.println("Enter message recipient");
            String recipient = keyboard.readLine();
            if (recipient == null) {
                System.out.println("No recipient username entered");
                }
                else if (recipient.contains(" ")) {
                System.out.println("Recipient username cannot contain spaces");
                }
            else {
            pw.println(recipient);
                        System.out.println("Enter message to be sent");
                String im = keyboard.readLine();
                pw.println(im);
            System.out.println(bf.readLine());
            }
            }
            else if (choice.equals("EXIT")) {
            pw.println("EXIT");
            System.exit(1);
            }
            else {
                    System.out.println("Error: you must either READ, COMPOSE or EXIT");
            }
        }

        }    


        // Catches the exception in which the server cannot be found
        catch(IOException e) {

            System.out.println("Error, could not connect to Server");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Sever.java

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        String request;

            // Makes sure that the user has specified the correct number of command line arguments
            if(args.length != 1) {
                System.err.println("Usage: java Server <port number>");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

            try (
            // Creates a server socket and waits for a connection
                ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);

                // A socket to communicate with the client
                Socket cs = ss.accept();

                // Reader and Writer to talk with Client
                PrintWriter pw =
                            new PrintWriter(cs.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(cs.getInputStream()));
            )

                // Links the server to the protocol     
            {
            Protocol protocol = new Protocol();
            protocol.storeUsername(bf.readLine());
            pw.println(protocol.messagesNumber());

            // Loop through user input until EXIT is entered
                while (true) {
                request = bf.readLine();
                // Controls output if user inputs READ
                if (request.equals("READ")) {
                    pw.println(protocol.messagesNumber());
                    if (protocol.messagesNumber() != 0) {
                        pw.println(protocol.readSender());
                        pw.println(protocol.readMessage());
                    }
                }
                // Controls input if user inputs COMPOSE
                else if (request.equals("COMPOSE")) {
                    String sender = bf.readLine();
                    String message = bf.readLine();
                    if (protocol.append(sender, message)) {
                    pw.println("MESSAGE SENT");
                }
                    else {
                    pw.println("MESSAGE FAILED");
                }
                }
                // Exits the server
                else {
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
            }


              // Catches the exception in which the server cannot find a client
              catch(IOException e) {
                  System.out.println("Failed to find a client");
                  System.exit(1);
              }      


       }
    }
```

Protocol.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Protocol {
    private String username;
    private String recipient;
    private String sender;
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> senderMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> messageMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();


    // Stores the username for the logged in user
    public void storeUsername(String user) {
    username = user;
    }

    // Stores the recipient name
    public void storeRecipient(String name) {
        recipient = name;
    }

    // Returns how many messages the logged in user has
    public int messagesNumber() {
    if(messageMap.containsKey(username))
        return messageMap.get(username).size();
    else
        return 0;
    }

    public boolean append(String recipient, String message) {
    boolean success = false;
    // If there is an entry for that name, just add the message to the end
        if(messageMap.containsKey(recipient)) {
        senderMap.get(recipient).add(username);
        messageMap.get(recipient).add(message);
        success = true;
        }
    // If there is no entry for that name, create a new entry with a list of messages and add the first message
    else {
        senderMap.put(recipient, new ArrayList<String>());
        senderMap.get(recipient).add(username);
        messageMap.put(recipient, new ArrayList<String>());
        messageMap.get(recipient).add(message);
        success = true;
    }
    return success;             
    }

     public String readSender() {

    // If the user has an entry and has at least 1 sender, return the least recent sender and then remove it  (the sender first in the list)
        if(senderMap.containsKey(username)) {

            if(senderMap.get(username).size() > 0) {
            String temp = senderMap.get(username).get(0);
            senderMap.get(username).remove(0);
            return temp;
        }
            else
            // If there are no messages left to read
            return "NO MESSAGES";
        }
        else
        // If the login hasn't been created yet
            return "NO MESSAGES";
    }


    public String readMessage() {

    // If the user has an entry and has at least 1 unread message, return the least recent unread message and then remove it (the first  message in the list)
        if(messageMap.containsKey(username)) {

            if(messageMap.get(username).size() > 0) {
            String temp = messageMap.get(username).get(0);
            messageMap.get(username).remove(0);
            return temp;
        }
            else
            // If there are no messages left to read
            return "NO MESSAGES";
        }
        else 
        // If the login hasn't been created yet
            return "NO MESSAGES";
    }


}
```

Comment: try with messages.length() == 0

Comment: Please post the full code of client and server. There may be a while or for loop above this.

Comment: @JithinKunjachan I will edit the post now

Comment: Most likely you are having problems with `{}` matching. Try to indent properly, f.ex. after the line `if(messageMap.get(username).size() > 0) {` and the issue will probably become clear.

Comment: @SantiBailors the indenting is correct in my files, I didn't realise it didn't paste correctly into the post.

Comment: TL;DR; Please post [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that you are fetching the "NO MESSAGES" twice.
Have a look at the code from *server.java*

```
 if (request.equals("READ")) {
   pw.println(protocol.messagesNumber());
   pw.println(protocol.readSender());
   pw.println(protocol.readMessage());
 }
```

This will call `readSender()` and `readMessage()` methods.

Now have a look at the return statements from both of these methods - `return "NO MESSAGES";`

Just set debug breakpoints in these two methods and debug and check!

Comment: I thought that, but I changed each of the "NO MESSAGES" statements to have a number following it, and only the client one was printing but it was printing twice? Even after deleting the return statements in server, it still prints both as it is due to the client "NO MESSAGES" statement.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt give you my most recent code. readSender and readMessage are only supposed to be accessed if there is more than 0 messages. See edit.

Comment: Yes, you might want to try out something like if((protocol.readSender()).equals("NO MESSAGES")) {//don't call readMessage() } else {//call  readMessage()}

Comment: I hope this would solve your problem. Kindly upvote and mark my solution as accepted if it really helped you. Thanks :D It will help me go long way!

Comment: sorry, I didn't realise I hadn't sent my most updated code. As you see now, I already have an if statement in there and it still prints twice

Comment: No problem. I guess, just update the if like I commented above.

Comment: Neither are being called if the user hasn't received any messages, so I'm unsure how that would help..? The "NO MESSAGES" is being returned from the client checking, not from the readSender method

Comment: The issue is I'm using if (Integer.parseInt(messages) == 0) in the client and it's throwing errors, but if I changed it to a string and make messages == "0", then it does equate properly and throws the double response.

Comment: @btoohey `equals` should be used to compare strings, not `==`.

Comment: @btoohey, could you please upvote and mark my solution as accepted? I would really appreciate it as I am spending some time on stackoverflow and helping people while trying to raise my points.

Comment: @DevendraLattu no sorry, that wouldn't be beneficial to other users as it didn't fix my issue